# Python import fails in Anaconda on OS X - "Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread"

Tags: python, anaconda

I am getting the following error when I am trying to import `AsperaTransferManager`:

```
from ibm_s3transfer.aspera.manager import AsperaTransferManager
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Abort trap: 6
```

Im working on MacOS 10.14.4, in anaconda environment with python 3.6.1

```
This is my Conda environment: 
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.7.1                    py36_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.7.1                    py36_0  
attrs                     19.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.6                h1de35cc_5  
c-ares                    1.15.0               h1de35cc_1  
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
cairo                     1.14.12              he60d9cb_2  
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py36_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cos-aspera                0.1.163682               pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.14                     pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.0                  hc84425e_0  
fontconfig                2.12.6               h9850fc5_0  
freetype                  2.8                  h12048fb_1  
gast                      0.2.2                    py36_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h2098e52_0  
grpcio                    1.14.1           py36h9011c5e_0  
h5py                      2.8.0            py36h878fce3_3  
harfbuzz                  1.7.6                h171471c_1  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hfa1e0ec_1  
ibm-cos-sdk               2.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ibm-cos-sdk-core          2.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer    2.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2019.3                      199  
ipykernel                 5.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jasper                    2.0.14               h636a363_1  
jedi                      0.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jmespath                  0.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
jsonschema                3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            5.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.2.4                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.7                      py_0  
keras-base                2.2.4                    py36_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                      py_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libopencv                 3.4.1                h0f2e407_1  
libopus                   1.3                  h1de35cc_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libprotobuf               3.5.2                h2cd40f5_0  
libtiff                   4.0.10               hcb84e12_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h378b8a2_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hab757c2_0  
lomond                    0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.1                      py36_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2019.3                      199  
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py36h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36h27c97d8_0  
mock                      2.0.0            py36hd48142b_0  
nbconvert                 5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
notebook                  5.7.8                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.16.3                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.3           py36h6575580_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py36_0  
opencv                    3.4.1            py36h6fd60c2_2  
openssl                   1.0.2r               h1de35cc_0  
pandas                    0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pbr                       5.1.3                      py_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    4.2.1            py36h0263179_0  
pip                       19.1                     py36_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h1de35cc_0  
prometheus-client         0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            2.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.5.2            py36h0a44026_1  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
py-opencv                 3.4.1            py36h9d9193e_1  
pygments                  2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.1                         2  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.1              py36h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 4.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.2.1            py36h1410ff5_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                41.0.1                   py36_0  
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
tabulate                  0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.9.0            py36hdc36e2c_0  
tensorflow                1.9.0           mkl_py36h4fc8490_1  
tensorflow-base           1.9.0           mkl_py36h70e0e9a_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1  
terminado                 0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
tornado                   6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.31.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.24.3                   pypi_0    pypi
watson-machine-learning-client 1.0.365                  pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  0.15.2                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.1                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

I saw related issues (https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/issues/1711) so I guess it could be some mismatch of different python versions but I don't know how to solve this or how to check if link the right python files.

I am not sure if this is linked to the problem or not, but it may help:

```
otool -L /Users/***/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cos_aspera/_faspmanager2.so
/Users/***/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cos_aspera/_faspmanager2.so:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)                        /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 58286.51.6)    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4) /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
```